# Would anyone please tell me what is wrong with my CSS file? When i call the primary color, it doesn't show in my html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i am using a css style sheet which is here: https://codepen.io/lorenzoyeung/pen/zYqxNQg

But when I do something like,

```
background-color: primary;
  border-color: secondary;
```

it won't work. Why is it? This is a CSS sheet i am going to use for my plotly web app.

Comment: To use CSS custom properties you need to use the right syntax:  `background-color: var(--primary)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for using CSS variables is : var(--variableName).
For your query the correct syntax should be:

```
background-color:var(--primary);
color:var(--secondary);
```

Comment: and why don't i need the "var" the other times? Sometimes i can just call "background-color: primary" and it works. I am so confused.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the RGB system with a syntax like:
background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0)
or using words like:
background-color: red

Comment: Got it! But why RGB is recommended over the others?

Comment: It's not, you can really use anything, I just personally prefer using RGB. You can use also use hex, but for me, it is easiest to use RGB